# OBJC Class referenced from when doing an Archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I just run the app on a simulator everything works fine.

Now I want to archive the app to upload it to testflight and I get these errors when archiving:

```
Ld /Users/user123/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLife-eoovatnxpocygjcdijxojtryqted/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Production/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CityLife.build/Release-iphoneos/Production.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Production normal arm64
    cd /Users/user123/Documents/Development/Comp/citylife_user_phone_app_ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/user123/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLife-eoovatnxpocygjcdijxojtryqted/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Production/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/user123/Documents/Development/Comp/citylife_user_phone_app_ios/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -F/Users/user123/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLife-eoovatnxpocygjcdijxojtryqted/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Production/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -FCityLife/Frameworks -F/Users/user123/Documents/Development/Comp/citylife_user_phone_app_ios -filelist /Users/user123/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLife-eoovatnxpocygjcdijxojtryqted/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Production/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CityLife.build/Release-iphoneos/Production.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Production.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -dead_strip -ObjC -lAFNetworkActivityLogger -lAFNetworking -lAFOAuth2Manager -lBase64 -lFXBlurView -lGVPhotoBrowser -lGoogleAnalytics -lHexColors -lISO8601DateFormatter -lJSONModel -lMBProgressHUD -lMagicalRecord -lMasonry -lMixpanel -lNSDate+RelativeTime -lPDKeychainBindingsController -lQR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C -lREMenu -lReliant -lSVProgressHUD -lTSMessages -lTTTAttributedLabel -lTTTLocalizedPluralString -lUICKeyChainStore -lUIScrollView-InfiniteScroll -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework Accelerate -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -framework CoreData -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreVideo -framework MobileCoreServices -framework KBCPaymentKit -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBookUI -framework Crashlytics -framework AddressBook -liconv -framework MessageUI -framework MapKit -lsqlite3 -framework CoreLocation -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user123/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLife-eoovatnxpocygjcdijxojtryqted/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Production/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CityLife.build/Release-iphoneos/Production.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Production_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user123/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CityLife-eoovatnxpocygjcdijxojtryqted/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Production/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CityLife.build/Release-iphoneos/Production.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Production

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CommunityRemoteService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CommunityDetailsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CommunityRewardsTableViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WishlistTableViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CommunityOverviewTableViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CommunityRewardDetailTableViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ProfileCommunityOverViewTableViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CommunityDealsTableViewController.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried things like adding the $(inherited) flag on the Pods target but nothing helps.

Someone knows whats wrong?

Comment: well they aren't arm64 bit I guess. try building a developer build for arm64

Comment: It looks like you're not building the correct architectures for a Release build -  can you add a screenshot of the Architecture section in the Build Settings for your target (you can see this if you select your project in the Project Navigator tab on the left hand side)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Because I've created the files with AppCode the files were only in the test target and not in the production target.

I've added them via xCode to the compile sources and now it works.